# como crear bloques o columnas en CSS3 de la siguiente forma:

Tags: html, css3, web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado crear una estructura a partir de  clases para agruparlas en cajas, también, también usando el atributo en CSS de columnas. Me habían sugerido usar "Float", pero no se bien como aplicarlo.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]! Para que tu pregunta reciba mejor respuestas te recomiendo que le eches un ojo a [ask]. Ya que no se suele recibir muy bien frases como la última que has puesto, y rara vez se contesta a una pregunta donde el OP no indique que ha intentado el, un ejemplo o errores que le han ido saliendo.

Comment: Si apenas estás arrancando, pásate por la [librería de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/overview/), su manejo de las columnas te sirve para lo que necesitas. Ya si luego de revisarla a fondo tienes problemas, indícanos cuáles has tenido, tal cual te lo menciona correctamente @rencinas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te he creado un ejemplo con tu estructura. Espero que te sirva:

```css
/*!
 *  JRCode 
 */
 body {
    background-color:#A9E8FF; 
    margin:0;
 }
.main { 
    width:100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:3%;
    margin:0;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    border:5px solid #C2AF03;
    background-color:#E7D10B;
}

.col1, .col2{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FEEB3C;
}

.col1 div, .col2 div{
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:3%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    border:1px solid black; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>columnas float</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="main">
        <header>INFORMACIÓN ADICIONAL</header>
        <section class="col1">
         <div>POLITICAS DE USO</div>
            <div>PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES</div>    
      </section>
        <section class="col2">
            <div>CARGOS ADICIONALES</div>
            <div>COBERTURAS Y GARANTÍAS</div>
            <div>bloque flotante</div>                    
        </section>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

A partir de ahí puedes generar los bloque que quieras y se alinean en dos columnas.

Comment: Gracias por la edición, aún no me entiendo bien con los snipets

Comment: La idea es ayudar a resolver un problema cuando la persona que pregunta muestra algún avance, no hacerle el trabajo completo.

Comment: Ok, la próxima así será :)

Comment: muchas gracias! me ha servido de mucha utilidad!

Comment: De nada! No olvides marcar la respuesta como útil ;)